# Dead Line exceed : Google Datastore Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have absolutely no load , one client. I am loading one record at a time , I have seen multiple times - i get error Deadline exceeded.

Have other people seen this kind of scenario.

And if with almost 0 load, performance is like this , is it even ok to use datastore in production

Update:
There is nothing special about insert or read , its a simple api , and it fails quite randomly

Comment: Can you retry using `exponential backoff` as suggested in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors#:~:text=DEADLINE_EXCEEDED,using%20exponential%20backoff).

Comment: What do you mean by you have no load but at the same time you're loading a record? Best thing is to update your question and include code showing how you're updating your record, the average size of your record. Also tell us if you're using GAE or Cloud Run and what your config is.

Comment: By Load means , 10s of requests per second, Its a direct call to the datastore from my local server , the same happens if if run it via google cloud run